# How can I run a scheduled task as SYSTEM

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler, windows-server

I can't add SYSTEM account in task scheduler. When I try to add it becomes MYDOMAIN\SYSTEM and I get invalid user error.

Can I use SYSTEM account to run a scheduled task?

Comment: AT command: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223375/en-us?fr=1

Comment: The correct name of the SYSTEM-account would be "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did try...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For Windows Server 2008 this is how to change to use the SYSTEM user account when executing a scheduled task:

1. Go to Start > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler
2. In the Task Scheduler window click "Create Task" on the right hand bar under the "Actions" pane
3. In the "Create Task" dialog click the "Change User or Group" button
4. Make sure "From this location" is set to the local machine name (to change click "Locations" button and select the local computer name)
5. Type "SYSTEM" in the text box and press ok
   . Under "When running the task, use the following user account:" you should see "NT AUTHORITY\**SYSTEM**".

Comment: I am having the same problem, but in "Change User or Group" I can't select the local machine?

Comment: You need local admin permissions to see / find the SYSTEM user. If the permissons was newly granted, you have to log off / log in again to see the user