# Task Scheduler - scheduled task to run as SYSTEM not fire

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

Following the answer here:

[How can I run a scheduled task as SYSTEM](https://superuser.com/questions/347751/how-can-i-run-a-scheduled-task-as-system)

I have created task to be run using SYSTEM account
[Task to be run on System account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YBjL.png)

But it does not start on scheduled time.

When I change it from system to my account it runs without problems

Why? Is it because "Run only when user is logged on" option checked? ( on the scheduled time I am logged to computer ). But this option is greyed - I can not change it.

Comment: You might want to check the event log for the task scheduler under "Application and Service Logs" -> "Microsoft" -> "Windows" -> "Task Scheduler".

Comment: event claims: "Task Scheduler succesfully finished for ... [my task]". But the scheduled program didn't start.

Comment: It most likely did - in the SYSTEM user context. That means you will not see any window popup, because it wasn't launched in your own user context. In the task manager, you might see the application running in the system user context.

Comment: Ok - you are probably right. But what if this application is for example AutoItScript, which runs another program and is clicking on its UI? Will it works correct?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if SYSTEM user actually gets a real user space generated to begin with - let alone window rendering. I think any UI related tasks might be troublesome.