# How does Windows 7/8/10 store and protect WiFi password?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, encryption, passphrase

> What encryption algorithm and what key is being used to encrypt WiFi
>   passphrase storage in Windows 10. I am trying to understand this.

I looked at the XML file at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\{INTERFACE UUID}` 
and the passphrase stored there appears to be protected by some kind of encryption.

It can't be the user's password since all users are able to access it. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: [Querying Wireless Settings and Decrypting Wireless Key](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577445/Querying-Wireless-Settings-and-Decrypting-Wireless)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Windows 10 Wifi location storage:**

For Windows 10 (like prior versions Windows Vista, 7 & 8), there is no longer the use of the registry to store information for the 'Wireless Configuration Manager'. There is now instead all information stored as you mentioned at following file,

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\{Random-GUID}.xml
```

You will find the wireless devices are each represented by its GUID {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} and its settings are stored in XML file with a random GUID name.

---

> **Understanding Windows 10 Encryption / Decryption**

It uses 'Windows Cryptography' functions - ([see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/cryptography-functions#data_encryption_and_decryption_functions)).

The signature at the beginning of each encrypted password is `01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C0`. So we can understand that 'Wireless Configuration Manager' uses CryptProtectData functions to encrypt the wireless keys and passwords.

Fortunately, decryption is as simple as using CryptUnprotectData, the catch is you need to run it as system. The ways that I know this can be done are:

1. Create a scheduled task as system - ([see here](https://superuser.com/a/604099/900431)). Be sure to make user as SYSTEM, then open task scheduler and run task, etc.
2. User System Internals program psexec64.exe
   *Windows Sysinternals is a part of the Microsoft TechNet website which offers technical resources and utilities to manage, diagnose, troubleshoot, and monitor a Microsoft Windows environment.* Download [here](https://live.sysinternals.com/).
3. If you run CMD as admin, navigate to the folder of the exe and then run the command `psexec64.exe -i -s cmd.exe` - [see here for more details](https://superuser.com/a/1416509/900431).
4. Or run powershell as admin then navigate to the exe and run

   `PsExec64.exe -i -s powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
5. (Risky but common) [Inject the code via remote thread in system process - LSASS.EXE](https://securityxploded.com/ntcreatethreadex.php)
6. Go to nirsoft.net and read up on there procedure.

---

***Also you will need to learn to work with C++ for the code below:***

---

```
//
// Wireless Key/Password Decryption Algorithm for Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8/Windows 10
//
void DecryptWiFiPassword(BYTE *buffer, DWORD dwSizeBuffer)
{
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut;

    DataIn.pbData = buffer;
    DataIn.cbData = dwSizeBuffer;

    if(CryptUnprotectData(&DataIn, 0, NULL, NULL,NULL,0,&DataOut))
    {
        printf("\n Wireless Key Password : %s", (char *) DataOut.pbData);

    }
 }
```

---

**What are the CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData Functions Based On?**

- Via Data Protection API.
- The user interfaces are available through the Windows SDK and MSDN Library. CryptProtectData function. CryptUnprotectData function.

---

**Data Protection Application-Programming Interface Explained**

Here is a brief synopsis taken from a Microsoft article with more information about CryptProtectData and DPAPI dated October 2001, as Windows 2000 was the start of data protection application-programming interface (API).

This Data Protection API (DPAPI) is a pair of function calls that provide operating system-level data protection services to user and system processes. They operate at the system-level and do not require any additional libraries. And the data protection is by means of encryption. Thus any program from this time had the ability to encrypt data with out needing any specific cryptographic code other than the necessary function calls to DPAPI. These calls are two simple functions with various options to modify DPAPI behavior.

DPAPI requires a password to protect information, thus it is a password-based data protection service. The downfall of this method is that it only rests on a password, so DPAPI uses proven cryptographic routines, specifically the strong Triple-DES algorithm, and strong keys to ensure protection.

DPAPI initially generates a strong key called a MasterKey, which is protected by the user's password. DPAPI uses a standard cryptographic process called Password-Based Key Derivation, described in PKCS #5 (Password-based Encryption Standard 2.1) ([see PKCS wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)), to generate a key from the password. This password-derived key is then used with Triple-DES ([see wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)) to encrypt the MasterKey, which is finally stored in the user's profile directory.

To familiarize you with DPAPI please read the [full article here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)) and see an article on [troubleshooting DPAPI here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/309408/how-to-troubleshoot-the-data-protection-api-dpapi).

The article applies to an older version of Windows, though the fundamentals as far as I can see are the same.

---

**An Explanation of the Process by Two Other People/Groups:**

- [Here is a PDF by blackhat](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-10/Picod_Jean-Michel/BlackHat-DC-2010-Picod-DPAPI-slides.pdf) explaining the process.
- [@HennoBrandsma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44769340/7811302) of Stack Overflow says "Essentially, the SHA-1 hash of your current password protects the DPAPI masterkeys, which protect in turn each DPAPI-blob (there is a per blob salt as well). Each masterkey has a GUID that identifies the password that is used to protect it. Each blob also has a GUID that identifies which masterkey was used to encrypt it. These masterkeys expire after three months and a new one is created, but the old ones are kept around."

---

**Examples About Encryption and Decryption**

[Nirsoft.net](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html), whom have made a free decryption program that works in Windows 10, says DPAPI decrypted data always begins with the following sequence of bytes, so you can easily detect it:

```
01 00 00 00 D0 8C 9D DF 01 15 D1 11 8C 7A 00 C0 4F C2 97 EB
```

[Nirsoft.net](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html) lists some examples for passwords and other data encrypted with DPAPI:

- Passwords of Microsoft Outlook accounts, stored in the Registry.
- Credentials files of Windows (i.e `C:\Users\[User Profile]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Credentials`)
- Wireless network keys as this article
- Passwords in some versions of Internet Explorer, in Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2`
- Passwords stored in the passwords file of Chrome Web browser ('Login Data' file in the profile of Chrome).
- Encrypted cookies in Chrome Web browser ('Cookies' file in profile)

Even they admit if decryption fails 'Try to decrypt the data by executing code inside lsass.exe process (Requires elevation)', so for system passwords this can be a difficult thing to do.

---

**Article Sources:**

- [Microsoft CryptoAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI)
- [Windows Data Protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10))
- [NirSoft DataProtectionDecryptor v1.06](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html)
- [Security Xploded Exposing the WiFi Password Secrets](https://securityxploded.com/wifi-password-secrets.php)
- [Stack Exchange: Which Encryption algorithm does ProtectedData use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873666/which-encryption-algorithm-does-protecteddata-use)
- [Stack Exchange: ProtectedData.Unprotect after User changes password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909894/protecteddata-unprotect-after-user-changes-password)
- [PDF Decrypting DPAPI dataJean-Michel Picod, Elie BurszteinEADS, Stanford University](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-10/Picod_Jean-Michel/BlackHat-DC-2010-Picod-DPAPI-slides.pdf)

**Free Tools**

- [DPAPIck](https://pypi.org/project/dpapick/) is a python toolkit to provide a platform-independant implementation
  of Microsoft's cryptography subsytem called DPAPI (Data Protection API).
- [DataProtectionDecryptor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html) is a powerful tool for Windows that allows you to decrypt passwords and other information encrypted by the DPAPI (Data Protection API) system of Windows operating system. You can use this tool to decrypt DPAPI data on your current running system and to decrypt DPAPI data stored on external hard drive.
- [WirelessKeyView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) recovers all wireless network security keys/passwords (WEP/WPA) stored in your computer by the 'Wireless Zero Configuration' service of Windows XP or by the 'WLAN AutoConfig' service of Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, and Windows Server 2008. It allows you to easily save all keys to text/html/xml file, or copy a single key to the clipboard. You can also export your wireless keys into a file and import these keys into another computer.

**DPAPI and Crypto Function Resources**

- [DPAPI Secrets. Security analysis and data recovery in DPAPI](https://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=28)
- [How to troubleshoot the Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/309408/how-to-troubleshoot-the-data-protection-api-dpapi)
- [Microsoft CryptUnprotectData function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata)
- [Microsoft CryptProtectData function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata)
- [Microsoft: Example C Program: Using CryptProtectData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/example-c-program-using-cryptprotectdata)
- [Microsoft: Decrypting Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/decrypting-data)
- [Microsoft: Cryptography](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/cryptography-portal)

**Examples**

- [Example C Program: Using CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa382377(v=vs.71))
- [CryptUnprotectData from powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/07558d3c-4cb7-4ece-868f-b8a6ac9d3ace/cryptunprotectdata-from-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)
- [Git Hub AonaSuzutsuki/EncryptDecrypt_Test](https://gist.github.com/AonaSuzutsuki/4ce40f3f2e3ae0669b91ec9aecc17853)
- [Decrypt WEP wlan profile key using CryptUnprotectData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765860/decrypt-wep-wlan-profile-key-using-cryptunprotectdata)

**Further Reading**

- [Wikipedia - PKCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)
- [Wikipedia - Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)
- [Server Falut - Windows DPAPI and password reset](https://serverfault.com/questions/953713/windows-dpapi-and-password-reset)
- [Querying Wireless Settings and Decrypting Wireless](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577445/Querying-Wireless-Settings-and-Decrypting-Wireless)
- [Reversing dpapi and stealing windows secrets offline](https://elie.net/talk/reversing-dpapi-and-stealing-windows-secrets-offline/)

**Ideas on How to Compile C and C++ Simply**

- [Walkthrough: Compile a C program on the command line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)
- [How to Compile/Execute C/C++ code in Notepad++ with MinGW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLpaYVIoXqc)
- [How To Setup Notepad++ for Writing C++ Programs](http://www.edparrish.net/common/npp4c.html)
- [How to compile/execute C++ code from within Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980134/how-to-compile-execute-c-code-from-within-notepad)

Comment: This is by far the most thorough answer I've ever seen in stackexchange. Thank you very much. I do have a follow-up question, though: What are the CryptProtectData/CryptUnprotectData functions based on? How is the session key mentioned in the docs generated and what specific algorithm do they use?

Comment: @EgeFeyzıoglu is your question now answered?